# Ajax pulls cached page i IE 8/9, but work fine in FF

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

It is weird- my ajax calls are returning cached in IE, while they are properly behaving in FF; any ideas why ?

```
function createRequestObject(){
    var req;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        //For Firefox, Safari, Opera
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        //For IE 5+
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else{
        //Error for an old browser
        alert('Your browser is not IE 5 or higher, or Firefox or Safari or Opera');
    }
    //alert (req);
    return req;
}

//Make the XMLHttpRequest Object
var http = createRequestObject();      

var head;

function sendRequestTwo(method, url, head1){
    head = head1
    if(method == "get" || method == "GET"){
        http.open(method,url);
        http.onreadystatechange = handleResponseTwo;
        http.send(null);
            }
}

function handleResponseTwo(){
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
        var response = http.responseText;
        if(response){  
            document.getElementById(head).innerHTML = response;
            //window.scrollBy(0, 200);
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: Add a timestamp to request URI. Or just use jQuery, then all the code you've there can be eliminated to 2 or 3 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same problem. IE can be very caching aggressive.

Try to add a timestamp to your url:

```js
url += '?ts=' + new Date().getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

IE caches ajax aggressively - add a querystring that has the date or something else unique to prevent it from happening.